# to_string not declared in scope

Tags: c++, ubuntu, qt-creator

I am trying to make the `to_string(NUMBER)` function work in my Ubuntu computer for weeks but it never ever works in the QT environment or anywhere else. My code works perfectly on my Mac osx, but when I try running it in Ubuntu it complains that `to_string` is not declared in scope. Any solutions to this would be greatly appreciated. I have tried to update the gcc compiler but it didn't fix the problem. Please help.

I am using QT Creator 4.8.1 and I am using C++ and latest version of Ubuntu.

```
int Bint::operator*(int temp){
    Bint b(to_string(temp));
    return ((*this)*b);
}
```

I was missing the QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x in the pro file.

Comment: You should post some of the code you have, so that we can have a look at it. How are you calling this `to_string()`?

Comment: Did you add `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x` in .pro file ?

Comment: do you prefix the call with std:: ?

Comment: yes I added the using namespace std

Comment: `to_string() || !to_string()`...  That is the question...

Comment: Hmmm... According to "My code works perfectly on my mac osx" mac's compiler adds c++11 support by default ? Didn't know it.

Comment: @paddy `0x2B | ~0x2B` that is `FF` ))

Answer (score 30):

There could be different reasons why it doesn't work for you: perhaps you need to qualify the name with `std::`, or perhaps you do not have C++11 support.

This works, provided you have C++11 support:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string s = std::to_string(42);
}
```

To enable C++11 support with g++ or clang, you need to pass the option `-std=c++0x`. You can also use `-std=c++11` on the newer versions of those compilers.

Comment: If anything is wrong with this answer, I'd like to know so I can fix it.

Comment: This answer should be selected as answer.

Answer (score 13):

you must compile the file with c++11 support

```
g++ -std=c++0x  -o test example.cpp
```

Comment: does Ubuntu not have C++11 yet?

Comment: @MattMcNabb yes it does but it depend on what version of ubuntu and gcc you have

Comment: @Frankenstein Where should I be writing that, "g++ -std=..."? I'm using codeblocks.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem by changing the first line in **Application.mk** from

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

to

```
APP_STL := c++_static
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some changes in the compiler.
In Dev C++ Compiler: 
1. Go to compiler settings/compiler Options.
2. Click on General Tab
3. Check the checkbox (Add the following commands when calling the compiler.
4. write -std=c++11
5. click Ok

Comment: after adding your given line i am facing this error D:\VU_classes\CS201\Assignments\g++.exe [Error] 5: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

This error, as correctly identified above, is due to the compiler not using c++11 or above standard. This answer is for **Windows 10**.

**For c++11 and above standard support in codeblocks version 17:**

1. Click **settings** in the toolbar.
2. A drop-down menu appears. Select **compiler** option.
3. Choose **Global Compiler Settings**.
4. In the toolbar in this new window in second section, choose **compiler settings**.
5. Then choose **compiler flags** option in below toolbar.
6. Unfold **general** tab. Check the **C++ standard** that you want your compiler to follow.
7. Click **OK**.

**For those who are trying to get C++11 support in Sublime text.**

1. Download **mingw compiler version 7** or above. In versions below this, the default c++ standard used is c++98 whereas in versions higher than 7, the default standard used is c++11.
2. Copy the folder in main C drive. It should **not** be inside any other folder in C drive.
3. **Rename the folder as MinGW**. This name is case insensitive, so it should any variation of mingw and must not include any other characters in the name.
4. Then go to **environment variables** and edit the path variable. Add this "**C:\mingw\bin**" and click OK.
5. You can check the version of g++ in cmd by typing `g++ -v`.
6. This should be sufficient to enable c++11 in sublime text.

If you want to take inputs and outputs as well from input files for competitive programming purposes, then follow this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/setting-up-a-c-competitive-programming-environment/).

Answer (score -1):

```
//Try this if you can't use -std=c++11:-
int number=55;
char tempStr[32] = {0};
sprintf(tempStr, "%d", number);
```