# How to execute an OS command from Cpp when it depends of code?

Tags: c++, windows

Let's say I have a function that takes an integer  `int m` as a parameter, and I want to create a file which name contains the value of m, such that; if I call `function(1);` the function creates the script: **scrp1.plt**, if I call `function(2);` it creates the script: **scrp2.plt** and so on.
Also, I want to execute an OS command from this Cpp script using the `system()` function, (I'm on Windows). If the OS command depends on parameter m, how must I pass it to the system function?. Specifically, I want to execute the script created before (suppose is a Gnuplot script);

```
void function(int m){
 ofstream file;
 file.open("scrp*.plt"); \\I dont know what I must write instead of the * sign to perform that task.
//some code
system("gnuplot scrp*.plt"); \\I dont know what I must write instead of the * sign to perform that task.
}
```

thanks in advance!.

Comment: Do you know how to concatenate strings with numbers?

Comment: @ChrisMM Not really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
void function(int m) {
    ofstream file;
    string filename = "scrp" + to_string(m) + ".plt";
    file.open(filename);
        //some code
    string scriptname = "gnuplot scrp" + to_string(m) + ".plt";
        system(scriptname); 
}
```

Comment: Well it seems that ```system()``` function accepts only types ```const char*``` and not string, I also have error: 'to_string()' was not declare in this scope but I get the idea, thanks.

Comment: @trsk In order to use string and to_string() you need to #include <string>.

Comment: system(scriptname.c_str());

Comment: @DanielRad  Yes, I did it, but the error persisted, the problem was that my compiler (g++) has not C++11 support. I did compile adding this command `-std=c++0x` as specified here [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569179/to-string-not-declared-in-scope). and it works fine, thanks again.

Comment: @nevilad When compiling with `-std = c ++ 0x` there is no need to convert, but in case I need it, I also tried using `c_str ()`and it works, thanks.